# Hide nav item from unity exported project : iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, uinavigationcontroller

I have integrated unity in iOS and worked well. But there is unexpected nav bar item. How to hide that nav item or remove it so that I can show my top item.

Here is the image of that item:

[image]

I also don't know how he is getting that name.
**After deleting nav item from storyboard also the item is there but without any name.**
And here is the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController;



UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
    storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    _rootController         = [[UnityPortraitOnlyViewController alloc] init];
    _rootView               = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    _rootController.view    = _rootView;

    ViewController *mainVC       = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];

    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];

    [_rootView addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
```

Comment: what is the black background ? you want hide  that ?

Comment: @KKRocks no i want to hide white nav bar

Comment: add this line after initwithrootViewController 
   - self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: @KKRocks It worked. Actually i was setting that before allocation of navigationcontroller. Silly me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```